# Clean URL - How to edit url variables for editing url name & delete folder name on redirect using htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

Despite there being thousands of questions similar to this I was unable to make it work for this specific situation.

### delete folder name on redirect

```
public_html+
|
|    htaccess
|    robots.txt
|
|    libraries+
|    |   classOne.php
|    |   classTwo.php
|
|    webroot+
|    |   css
|    |   images
|    |   js
|    |   index.php
|    |   article.php
```

The following seems to always redirect my main domain to webroot/ as I want but how do I go by deleting the webroot folder name from the url so that it looks like

**www.example.com/**
instead of
**www.example.com/webroot**

I'm using the following code for this..

```
RewriteBase /webroot/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

---

### Mask variables & include folder name instead

I've got an article.php which I'd like to edit the URL to look better for SEO.

In my real domain currently it's showing as below..

**www.example.com/webroot/article.php?article_uid=33&article_title=Apple,%20Microsoft%20And%20Free%20Software**

I'd like to edit the above to show like this..

www.example.com/article/id/title-goes-here

I have tried with the following code but nothing has changed at all. The only thing I don't know how is to add the slashes to the title.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Why is your `webroot` in the url anyways? You should fix this in the apache2 virtualhost file and set the DocumentRoot to be  `/path/to/webroot`  so that the webroot ... is well actually the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /webroot/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /webroot/
RewriteRule ^webroot/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webroot/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webroot/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Jon. After adding the following code into the htaccess there seems to be a loop where it does not redirect to webroot's index.php and just shows the folders on the document root. libraries, webroot, .htaccess & robots.txt but when I click the webroot it just redirects back to the same page.

Comment: @AttisBarros change the last line from `/webroot/$1` to `/webroot/index.php`.

Comment: I have tried the following as you have pointed out but continues with the loop for some reason, have cleared cache as well to double check.

Comment: @AttisBarros Well, you could try getting rid of the 2nd and 4th (last) rules, and going back to using your routing into webroot. And just using the 1st and 3rd to deal with the articles.